# Changing the cell background color of a 'DataGridView' in virtual mode

Tags: c#, winforms

I am just learning how to use a `DataGridView` control in virtual mode. I'm using a list array to store the contents of a text file that could be small or quite large. One particular column in the `DataGridView` needs to have the background color of the cell changed based on the text content in that cell.  So, I have an event handler:

```
private void datagridview_CellValueNeeded(
    object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
```

that populates each row of the `DataGridView`. My problem is that I don't know where to insert the code to set the **background color** as the cells are created in each row (now in virtual mode).

I tried using an event handler for `CellValueNeeded` to first check for a particular column ID and then setting the cell background color as follows:

```
datagridview[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.SelectionBackColor =
    component_color;
```

where `component_color` was predetermined. However, this approach didn't change the color. I also tried handling other events such as `CellEnter`, `CellLeave`, `CellValueChanged`, `RowsAdded` and `RowLeave`. However, I learned from my debugging effort that these events either never fire or fire before the `CellValueNeeded` event.

So, is it possible to set the background color of a cell as it is created in a particular column by handling the `CellValueNeeded` event? Or should I accomplish this by handling a different event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event. For example:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 3 && e.Value == targetValue)
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    else
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: is it efficient to set the BackColor property? Isn't more efficient to set the DefaultCellStyle for the column with index 3 to a `new DataGridViewCellStyle{BackColor = SystemColors.Window}` assigned in the constructor? And, since many cells may contain the targetValue, would it be more efficient to store a `new DataGridViewCellStyle{BackColor = Color.Red}` in a private class field and reuse it?

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it? I mean, you select a 4 years old answer and come asking whether it is the most efficient way to accomplish what the original poster was asking for. Did you see anyone complain about possible performance issues? I think you're trying to bring up a non-existing performance issue.

Comment: I fear I got misunderstood, sorry.

Comment: It is never too late to improve an answer, IMO. StackOverflow very nature is to collaboratively work on giving the most precise and complete answer(s) to ALL of the readers, not only the OP. Asking for clarification and/or proposing alternatives it's a Good Thing (TM)

Comment: @LorenzoDematté Yes, I agree, but making assertions about the efficiency of a solution versus another one without any backing data is pretty pointless IMO. If at least the person had come to the discussion with "I ran a benchmark on your solution, and found this other solution to be more efficient". No, he made some assertions based on a hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Despite [Luc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172769/luc-morin) answer is formally correct and would work in all scenarios, it is worth noting that assigning single properties on CellStyle property will Clone() the full original inherited style.

[The best practices suggested by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/best-practices-for-scaling-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) and the [hierarchy detailed explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/cell-styles-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) clearly state (and explain why) DataGridViewCellStyle should be reused whenever possible.

The trick is that since CellStyle contains the inherited style, you cannot directly change it, thus it has to be cloned before accessing it. If you have 1000 cells that match "target", then you clone 1000 time the same inherited style just to apply 1000 time the same one (with red back color). So the best practice says: set the column default to the expected default style for that column, then create the "highlight" cell style once and reuse it when possible.

In almost all scenarios the difference will not be noted and no penalty of any kind (memory, cpu, flickering, etc...) would be noted. Nevertheless, I believe it is important to understand that under the hood a lot of stuff is going on. Moreover, CellFormatting is called very often so it's very important to keep the underlying operations very quick in order to avoid side effects.

The above answer could also be rewritten this way:

```
private static DataGridViewCellStyle m_targetValueCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle{ BackColor = Color.Red};

// Somewhere (i.e. in the constructor after InitializeComponents() ) set:
// dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle{ BackColor = SystemColors.Window};

private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 3 && e.Value == targetValue)
        e.CellStyle = m_targetValueCellStyle;
}
```

This approach can be quite limited in very complex scenarios because you need to know all styles and combination beforehand (e.g. red back color, white fore color but also red back color, black fore color and bold) and that may be tricky and cumbersome. I thought it would have been worth mentioning anyway what Microsoft suggests. It's not a matter of pure performance here, it's more a matter of *know what you are doing and what is happening* in order to pick the best (where what is best depends on the scenario) strategy. I believe we need to teach young programmers to make informed choices when developing.

Please consider my answer not alternative, yet complementary to Luc's one.

A

Comment: I invite you to read the "Setting Styles Dynamically" section again. It clearly states that in the `CellFormatting` event, you get a `CellStyle` object, and that "You can modify the cell style properties to specify style information appropriate to the cell value and location". Notice that Microsoft themselves tell users to set the properties of the `CellStyle` object. I will restate my comment, to your comment, with the same question: "why don't you benchmark it?". Bring us the benchmark results, and then we can discuss a real issue, and not just a hypothetical one.